# 's' term in WP_Query extended class causes huge memory leak (268MB)

Tags: wp-query

I've used [WP-Geo-Posts](https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp-geo-posts) as a starting point for building a plugin which extends WooCommerce to support classifieds-like functionality. Using [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) I've associated products with a location (latitude and longitude) and I'm now building location support into search. Users provide search terms, a location and a radius. Results should be products within a certain radius, ordered by closest to the provided location. It's working perfectly, but the search is currently ignoring any search terms the user enters.

I've made a class which extends WP_Query to build the pseudo-field of 'distance'. You'd think I could just provide `s` to the same `$args` array, and it would scope by keyword like WP_Query does. Instead I get a blank page and the logs say

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/mydir/home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 1681, referer: http://example.com/shop/
```

I have this which works fine:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => $query->get('post_type') ,
  'posts_per_page'  => 20,
  'fields'          => 'all',
  'lat'             => $_REQUEST['lat'],
  'lng'             => $_REQUEST['lng'],
  'distance'        => $_REQUEST['dist']
);
$query = new WP_Query_Geo( $args );
```

And this which leaks memory like gangbusters:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => $query->get('post_type') ,
  'posts_per_page'  => 20,
  'fields'          => 'all',
  'lat'             => $_REQUEST['lat'],
  'lng'             => $_REQUEST['lng'],
  'distance'        => $_REQUEST['dist'],
  's' => $search_terms
);
$query = new WP_Query_Geo( $args );
```

My class which extends WP_Query (WP_Query_Geo) uses concats (`.=`) on $fields, $join and $where so I don't see why providing `s` should do any harm.

This is the output of `var_dump($query->request);` without the `s` in $args:

```
string(799) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(48.4284207) ) * cos( radians( latitude.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( longitude.meta_value ) - radians(-123.36564440000001) ) + sin( radians(48.4284207) ) * sin( radians( latitude.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distance , latitude.meta_value AS latitude , longitude.meta_value AS longitude FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS latitude ON wp_posts.ID = latitude.post_id INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS longitude ON wp_posts.ID = longitude.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND latitude.meta_key="lat" AND longitude.meta_key="lng" HAVING distance <= 100 ORDER BY distance ASC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20"
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($query->request);`?

Comment: I've added it to the question. I can't get `$query->request` (or anything else) when `s` is included because of the fatal error.

Comment: I made a small test case. Just hooking into `pre_get_posts` and var_dumping `$query->request`, I get `NULL`.

Comment: you won't have `$query->request` on the `pre_get_posts` hook. It is too soon.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I've made a gist here: https://gist.github.com/archonic/2d57320ae438745146c3

Comment: Comparing the var_dumps of `$wp_query` and `$geo_query`, the latter has a bunch of post data. Perhaps the `WP_Query_Geo` class constructor isn't supposed to actually perform the query?

Comment: I don't know. I know nothing about that plugin. You should contact the plugin's author.

Comment: It hasn't been updated in years and I'm writing my own plugin with a host of related features. I was able to get it working by writing a hook into the archive template which overwrites the global $wp_query. That seems goofy to me - I should be able to interrupt default searching functionality with `pre_get_posts` and query using an extended class while keeping search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what convention is with `pre_get_posts`, but it seems to be for setting additional arguments and not replacing then running the query. Comparing wp_query and my own geo query, I noticed my own had post data in the query object. This may have been what caused the memory leak, but it must have had an infinite loop - my entire DB is no where near 268MB. Perhaps the query is not meant to take place inside the constructor? I'd love to know of a solution using `pre_get_posts`.

Instead of using `pre_get_posts`, I used the `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` hook to replace `$wp_query` altogether.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wr_product_geo_query');
function wr_product_geo_query() {
  global $wp_query;

  if ($wp_query->is_search() && isset($_REQUEST['loc'])) {
    $args = array(
      'post_type'       => $_REQUEST['post_type'] ,
      'posts_per_page'  => 20,
      'fields'          => 'all',
      'lat'             => $_REQUEST['lat'],
      'lng'             => $_REQUEST['lng'],
      'distance'        => $_REQUEST['dist'],
      's' => $_REQUEST['s']
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query_Geo( $args );
  }
}
```

Pretty simple, but I'd like a solution that inserts itself into default search behaviour instead of relying on a template hook.

Update: After much internal deliberation, I believe pre_get_posts is exclusively for modifying an existing query. I'm not modifying it, I'm nuking it. In which case, creating a new query object via a custom template or template hook is the "proper" way to do it.

Comment: You are wrong, you can replace query settings in `pre_get_posts`, in fact that is the most common use case I've seen and I do. Anyway, your problem seems to be related with a code we have not access and you have not posted, so no one here can give you the answer.

Comment: I posted a gist in the comments of the question. It's not a functioning plugin but if you know what's going on, it should be enough to identify the issue https://gist.github.com/archonic/2d57320ae438745146c3

Comment: I'm also not looking to "replace query settings" (with `$query->set()`) but replace the WP_Query object entirely with my own class that extends WP_Query.

Comment: you are creating an infinite loop. your `pre_get_posts` function checks if `is_search`, then runs another query, which fires your `pre_get_posts` function again, over and over ad infinitum. you need an additional check of some sort to prevent your embedded query from running the same query you're already inside of.

Comment: I thought that might be the case! I've seen other examples that used `is_search` inside `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: That wasn't the case -_-. I removed all conditionals before `$args` and it's still running an infinite loop. There's something weird about the `s` arg. It's like it expects to be run on an already populated query object.

Comment: I've narrowed it down. The infinite loop happens with `parent::query( $args );` in `__construct` on my class. Looking at the WP_Query (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/64fc7294b6c4359345f5fb506c1d4d2c6efd9746/wp-includes/query.php), it looks like `$query_vars_changed` isn't being set to false, which keeps running `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: It seems like `fill_query_vars` is emptying `s`, then `pre_get_posts` is run, then `$query_vars_changed` is true and the cycle starts all over. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/64fc7294b6c4359345f5fb506c1d4d2c6efd9746/wp-includes/query.php#L1393

Is there some magical way to supply `s` in `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: I believe `pre_get_posts` is exclusively for modifying an existing query. I'm not modifying it, I'm nuking it. In which case, creating a new query object via a custom template or template hook is the "proper" way to do it. I'm done :)